# How to return void from std::tuple_element if index is out of range?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stdtuple

I have a function traits struct that provides the types of a function's arguments using `std::tuple_element`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
struct function_traits;

template <typename T_Ret, typename ...T_Args>
struct function_traits<T_Ret(T_Args...)> {
    // Number of arguments.
    enum { arity = sizeof...(T_Args) };
    // Argument types.
    template <size_t i>
    struct args {
        using type
            = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<T_Args...>>::type;
    };
};

int main() {
    using Arg0 = function_traits<int(float)>::args<0>::type;
    //using Arg1 = function_traits<int(float)>::args<1>::type; // Error, should be void.

    std::cout << typeid(Arg0).name() << std::endl;
    //std::cout << typeid(Arg1).name() << std::endl;
}
```

[Working example: Ideone](http://ideone.com/qM9Jxp)

If the index `i` is out of range (`>= arity`), this gives a compile-time error. Instead, I would like `args<i>::type` to be `void` for any `i` out of range.

While I can specialize `args` for specific `i`, such as `i == arity`, how could I go about specializing `args` for all `i >= arity`?

Comment: can you extend the code for us. So we can compile this? Like with a simple use case etc.

Comment: @Hayt Done: http://ideone.com/qM9Jxp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `std::conditional` and extra indirection:

```
struct void_type { using type = void; };


template <typename T_Ret, typename ...T_Args>
struct function_traits<T_Ret(T_Args...)> {
    // Number of arguments.
    enum { arity = sizeof...(T_Args) };

    // Argument types.
    template <size_t i>
    struct args {
        using type
            = typename std::conditional<(i < sizeof...(T_Args)),
                                        std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<T_Args...>>,
                                        void_type>::type::type;
    };
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/yR6B5P)